# How to add space to a webpage?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a resume webpage. I am using Bootstrap 4 to aide me with responsive design. I am struggling with spacing different collapsible (div) elements.

I looked up some resources on w3schools. I saw that I can use HTML br tag to create a new line in a paragraph. However, that does not add a newline (space) between different elements.

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <p>Some text here. </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently, I am using an empty p tag (see above) to add space between a collapsible element and the following element. However, is there any other way to add space? Or, is this method independent of the viewport/device?

Comment: You should add bottom padding or margin to your `#demo` div.

Comment: So is using <p></p> wrong for some reason?

Comment: It's just unnecessary markup. If you did that everywhere you'd have some messy code. Keep markup as small as possible. See my answer below to see how to properly add spacing (via padding/margins) using bootstrap.

Comment: What you are asking is kind of a broad topic. Simply introducing elements as a workaround for another line break is certainly an option, but really getting into the spacial organization of a page is an art all in itself. Here is some light reading on the topic: https://medium.com/refactoring-ui/7-practical-tips-for-cheating-at-design-40c736799886 .

Comment: An additional reason to not have empty elements is when you start to factor in web accessibility. Adding in HTML elements for the sake of changing the display could throw them off and cause blind/deaf users not to be able to accurately use your site. 

Using custom CSS is a much better way. You get the space you want while at the same time keeping your HTML clean and accessible.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Bootstrap, you can use Bootstrap's spacing utilities to add spacing where you need.

**Example:**

Change

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
```

to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
```

Notice I added the `mb-3` class to the button? That's adding spacing below it.

You can read more about bootstrap's spacing utilities [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/).

Answer (score 1):

Add Custom CSS to the document

```
<style>
#demo{
     margin-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

So 1st of all great that you are learning HTML.

the issues I see in your code:

div#demo is been used to wrap text see [div docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div). So div should be used for content layout if you need a text wrapper use `p`(block) `span`(inline), there are more but they are the basics.

If you check [Browser DefaultValues](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) you will see that `p` tag has the margin you lack on #demo.

So the simplest thing to do is to add `p` around the 1st paragraph

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>Some text here. </p>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also replace the empty < p > tag with a line-break < br > tag

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary" 
          data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#demo">
    Simple collapsible
  </button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>Some text here. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use `<br />`. You need to use a few (about 3 or 4) to get a space between the elements.